# AWS Cognito - Developer Authenticated Identities in JavaScript(Browser)

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have trouble getting credentials in a browser script.

The authentication server returns cognito_identityId and cognito_token.

Then I set a Cookie:

- $.cookie('cognito_identityId')
- $.cookie('cognito_token')

I tried to get credentials in 4 ways on the browser, and all Failed:

1. CognitoIdentityCredentials

   ```
   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
       IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx'
       IdentityId: $.cookie('cognito_identityId'),
       Logins: {
           'myauth': $.cookie('cognito_token')
       }
   });
   ```

   // => Error: Missing required key 'IdentityId' in params
2. assumeRoleWithWebIdentity

   ```
   var params = {
     RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/Cognito_xxxxxxxAuth_Role',
     RoleSessionName: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
     WebIdentityToken: $.cookie('cognito_token'),
     DurationSeconds: 900,
     ProviderId: 'myauth'
   };
   var sts = new AWS.STS({apiVersion: '2011-06-15'});
   sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
   ```

   // => AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

PolicyDocument

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
    "Sid": "",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

3. GetCredentialsForIdentity

   ```
   var params = {
       IdentityId: $.cookie('cognito_identityId'),
       Logins: {
         "myauth": $.cookie('oauth.io_token')
       }
   };
   var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});
   cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     }
     else {
       console.log(data);           // successful response
     }
   });
   ```

   // => InvalidParameterException: Please provide a valid public provider
4. WebIdentityCredentials

   ```
   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials({
       RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/Cognito_xxxxxxxxxxAuth_Role',
       WebIdentityToken: $.cookie('cognito_token')
   });
   ```

   // => Error: There were 2 validation errors:
   //   * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'IdentityPoolId' in params
   //   * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'IdentityId' in params

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- What is the correct way to use this?

Thank you.

---

Thank you for your kindness.

I tyied your advice, but did not change.

Error messages.

```
POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
Error: Missing required key 'IdentityId' in params
    at fail (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:2163:37)
    at validateStructure (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:2084:14)
    at validateMember (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:2110:21)
    at validate (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:2059:10)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:800:32)
    at Request.callListeners (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:3913:20)
    at callNextListener (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:3903:12)
    at chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:787:9
    at finish (chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:126:7)
    at chrome-extension://hmjdjbikinkmjbilihjibcihbkbjdgjf/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.js:142:9
```

There are source code below link.

https://github.com/bisque33/my-custom-dictionary

and server side is a AWS Lambda Function.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var cognitoidentity = new aws.CognitoIdentity();
var identityPoolId = 'us-east-1:0dccff0d-5fd7-4d14-b38f-d27204feaecc';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('token: %s', event.token);

    var params = {
        IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
        Logins: {
            'oauth.io': event.token
        }
    };
    cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('Something went wrong');
        }else{
            context.succeed(data);
        }
    });
};
```

This program is Google-Chrome-Extension.

- AWS Lambda Function returns token by getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.
- app/scripts/popup.js calls Lambda Function and set cookies.
- app/scripts/background.js calls AWS.config.credentials.get, and returns error.

Am I using it wrong?

---

### Update for Additional Information

Thank you for the additional information.

Error appears on 104 line on background.js

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
```

and 115 line on background.js

```
      dataset.synchronize(
```

And, My explaination was not enough. Facebook authentication needs the domain(ex. http :// example.com). However, Google-Chrome-Ext does not have domain. It has a domain 'chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'. Then, I use https://oauth.io. It proxies any authentication and accepts chrome-extension domain.

Popup.js does Facebook authentication through oauth.io sdk. It gets a facebook token, and gives to getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. I think facebook token.substr(0,14) is unique. But, If it is wrong, I use another unique identifier(ex. email-address.)

---

Sorry, I was wrong. AWS.config.credentials.get gives an Error:

```
Error: Invalid login token.
```

And, dataset.synchronize shows this Error:

```
Error: Missing required key 'IdentityId' in params
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I revised point 1 in my answer and added another section about "Facebook Login & Redirects". Please see my revised anwser.

Comment: Hi @Ryosuke , Are you able to resolve `GetCredentialsForIdentity` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first approach you have, using [CognitoIdentityCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html), is most likely the best approach for you to take. I can't spot exactly what's causing the error for you but lets try a couple things:

1. When using [Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/), you do need to specify the IdentityId when initializing [CognitoIdentityCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html). You need to get the IdentityId value from the call to GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. However, you shouldn't need to preserve the IdentityId value in a cookie as [CognitoIdentityCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html) will cache the id by default in the browser's local storage.
2. As for your Logins map: It looks like you're trying to use [Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/). With the JavaScript SDK, use the key `'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'` and make sure the value is the token returned from your backend's call to `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity`.

If you continue to have problem using the CognitoIdentityCredentials approach, please reply here with some more info such as the exact method/code you're calling when you receive the error message, and the traced output (i.e. with console.log('%o',..)) of the params input just before your call to the CognitoIdentityCredentials constructor.

---

### Update Based on Additional Information Provided

I still need to know exactly which line of code you receive the error on, but based on the information provided I think I can still help...

Based on what I see in [background.js](https://github.com/bisque33/my-custom-dictionary/blob/master/app/scripts/background.js#L31), it looks like you're trying to initialize CognitoIdentityCredentials using a Developer Authenticated Identities provider. This is where I'm guessing that you're receiving the error.

However, in [Popup.js](https://github.com/bisque33/my-custom-dictionary/blob/master/app/scripts/popup.js#L18), it looks like you're trying to authenticate the user with Facebook. If you're authenticating your users with Facebook, you should just pass the facebook access token into your Logins map when using Cognito. Just use `graph.facebook.com` as the key in the Logins map and the access token from Facebook. More detail on how to do this is in the [Facebook Integration topic of the Amazon Cognito developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/facebook/).

#### Facebook vs Developer Authenticated Identities

We can get Developer Authenticated Identities to work for you, but in this case, it doesn't look like the right solution for you since you're not actually doing any additional authentication on the identity in your Lambda function and the unique user identifier that you're passing into the `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` operation appears to be the facebook token, which is not good by the way since the token itself will change between user sessions even for the same user. Usually a good unique identifier is an email address or a user id used by an internal system.

#### Facebook Login & Redirects

Since you're ultimately trying to use Facebook for login and Amazon Cognito has [built-in integration for Facebook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/facebook/), the best thing for you to do is get an access token from Facebook and pass in the Facebook token to Cognito's login map directly. I'm not sure if this will work with Auth.io or not (I'm just not familiar with it), but as long as Auth.io gives your JavaScript code a bonefide facebook token and you add the same Facebook App ID to both Auth.io and Amazon Cognito's Console, it should work. However, you mentioned you want to use Auth.io to avoid Facebook doing a redirect to a landing page. I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure if you're using [Facebook's JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4) you won't need a redirect page. You should only need the redirect page if you're doing [Facebook's Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

Comment: thank you additional information. I added infomation,too.

Comment: @RyosukeIgarashi Sorry for the delay. I revised point 1 in my answer and added another section about "Facebook Login & Redirects". Please see my revised anwser.

Comment: Very very thank you! I resolved. I didn't need my developers authentifate identities. Google-Chome-Ext didn't use a Facebook's JavaScript SDK because it didn't have a correct domain. I used Oauth.io's SDK. It returned facebook token, and it set to 'graph.facebook.com'. Then AWS.config.credentials.get successed.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to login map 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com' with the token when calling getCredentialsForIdentity()